# agrupar valores tabla DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
ENVIO  ORDEN  LOTE
00011    1     6666
00011    2     6666
00012    3     7777
00012    4     7777
00012    5     8888
00013    6     9999
```

Necesito obtener de esa tabla, la siguiente:

```
ENVIO   CTDORDEN  LOTE
00011     2        6666
00012     2        7777
00012     1        8888
00013     1        9999
```

Tengo que obtener todos los diferentes lotes, y contar cuantas ordenes hay en cada lote y cada envio.
Intento hacer un `SELECT DISTINCT` pero no doy con la formula....
gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El `DISTINCT` actua bajo los resultados proyectados, mostrando solo uno de cada uno, independientemente de que forme las columnas o en general de que sea la consulta, el `DISTINCT` retornara una sola linea por cada "combinación" de valores (valga la redundancia) distintos. Como bien fue respondido, lo que necesitabas eran funciones agregadas bajo las agrupaciones necesarias. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas un `GROUP BY` + `COUNT` en vez de `DISTINCT`:

```
select envio, count(*) as ctdorden, lote
  from tabla
 group by envio, lote
 order by envio, lote
```

Comment: Muchas gracias¡¡¡¡¡¡